# In R Shiny, how to write a function that generates additional user inputs upon clicking an action button?

Tags: r, function, shiny

I'm working on an App that allows the user to optionally expand a base starting input (`firstInput` in the below MWE). `SecondInput` allows the user to vertically expand his assumptions (doesn't work in this MWE but in full App it runs extrapolations and interpolations, and it expands vertically fitting well in a sidebar panel). `ThirdInput` below is neutered for illustration simplicity. `FourthInput`, appearing in `modalDialog`, allows user to expand assumptions horizontally. The inputs are sequentially chained (`firstInput` -> `secondInput` -> `fourthInput`) with the last input taking precedence. Chaining works fine.

In full App I have vertical expansion working. Now I need help with horizontal assumption expansion.

As shown in the image at the bottom, in the modalDialog, how can I have a click of the "Add scenario" `actionButton` add another input matrix to the right, called "fifthInput"? Another click would add "sixthInput" to the right, etc. This is what I mean by "horizontal expansion". As far as chaining, these new inputs matrices would be chained to `secondInput` just like `fourthInput` is. A click of the "Remove above" `actionButton` would remove the input matrix immediately above it. I'm not sure how large a `modalDialog` box expands but I may need some kind of box that allows vertical/horizontal scrolling. If this is a bit much, I wonder if there's some sort of package that does or helps with this.

MWE code:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinyjs)
    library(shinyMatrix)

f <- function(action,i){as.character(checkboxInput(paste0(action,i),label=NULL))}
actions       <- c("show", "reset")
tbl           <- t(outer(actions, c(1,2), FUN = Vectorize(f)))
colnames(tbl) <- c("Show", "Reset")
rownames(tbl) <- c("2nd input", "3rd input")

firstInput <- function(inputId){
  matrixInput(inputId, 
              value = matrix(c(5), 1, 1, dimnames = list(c("1st input"),NULL)),
              rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols =  list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

secondInput <- function(inputId,x){
  matrixInput(inputId, 
              value = matrix(c(x), 1, 1, dimnames = list(c("2nd input"),NULL)),
              rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols =  list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

fourthInput <- function(inputId,x){
  matrixInput(inputId, 
              value = matrix(c(x), 1, 1, dimnames = list(c("4th input"),NULL)),
              rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols =  list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      "td .checkbox {margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;}
       td .form-group {margin-bottom: 0;}"
    ))
  ),
  br(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("panel"),
      hidden(uiOutput("secondInput")),
      actionButton("showFourth","Show 4th input (in modal)",width = "100%") # ADDED
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  input1      <- reactive(input$input1)
  input2      <- reactive(input$input2)
  input4      <- reactive(input$input4)
  
  output$panel <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      useShinyjs(),
      firstInput("input1"),
      strong(helpText("Generate curves (Y|X):")),
      tableOutput("checkboxes") 
    )
  })
  
  output[["checkboxes"]] <- 
    renderTable({tbl}, 
      rownames = TRUE, align = "c",
      sanitize.text.function = function(x) x
    )

  observeEvent(input[["show1"]], {
    if(input[["show1"]]){shinyjs::show("secondInput")} else 
      {shinyjs::hide("secondInput")}
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$showFourth,{
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        column(4,
          actionButton("add","Add scenario"), div(style = "margin-bottom: 10px"),
          fourthInput("input4",if(isTruthy(input$input4)){input$input4} else {input$input2[1,1]}),
          actionButton("remove","Remove above")
          ),
        footer = modalButton("Close")
      )) # close showModal and modalDialog 
  })
  
  output$secondInput <- renderUI({
    req(input1())
    secondInput("input2",input$input1[1,1])
  })
  
  outputOptions(output,"secondInput",suspendWhenHidden = FALSE) 
  
  output$plot1 <-renderPlot({
    req(input2())
    plot(rep(if(isTruthy(input$input4)){input4()} else {input2()}, times=5))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always underestimate package shinyMatrix, turns out it has the horizontal extension feature I'm looking for and extensions can be grouped in 2's as I need. See modified MWE code reflecting this usage of shinyMatrix for extensions. Basically for the column specifications for `matrixInput` (in custom function `fourthInput`), all I did was add `extend = TRUE, delta = 2, delete = TRUE, ....` Extend means the matrix can be expanded (column-wise since this is in the column parameters section), delta of 2 = matrix expands in grouping of 2, delete = columns can be deleted.

However shinyMatrix output isn't the prettiest thing out there, I'm open to other solutions or packages!!

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

f <- function(action,i){as.character(checkboxInput(paste0(action,i),label=NULL))}
actions       <- c("show", "reset")
tbl           <- t(outer(actions, c(1,2), FUN = Vectorize(f)))
colnames(tbl) <- c("Show", "Reset")
rownames(tbl) <- c("2nd input", "3rd input")

xDflt <- 10
yDflt <- 5

userInput <- function(inputId,x,y,z){
  matrixInput(inputId, 
              value = matrix(c(x,y), 1, 2, dimnames = list(c(z),c("X and Y",""))),
              rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols =  list(
                extend = FALSE, 
                names = TRUE, 
                editableNames = FALSE,
                multiheader=TRUE
              ),
              class = "numeric")}

fourthInput <- function(inputId,x,y,z){
  matrixInput(inputId, 
              value = matrix(c(x,y), 1, 2, dimnames = list(c(z),c("X and Y",""))),
              label = "Add, delete, or modify matrix parameters:",
              rows =  list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE),
              cols =  list(
                extend = TRUE,
                delta = 2,
                delete = TRUE,
                names = TRUE, 
                editableNames = FALSE,
                multiheader=TRUE
              ),
              class = "numeric")}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
      "td .checkbox {margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;}
       td .form-group {margin-bottom: 0;}"
    ))
  ),
  br(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("panel"),
      hidden(uiOutput("secondInput")),
      actionButton("showFourth","Show 4th input (in modal)",width = "100%")
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot1"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  input1      <- reactive(input$input1)
  input2      <- reactive(input$input2)
  input4      <- reactive(input$input4)
  
  output$panel <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      useShinyjs(),
      userInput("input1",xDflt,yDflt,"1st input"),
      strong(helpText("Generate curves (Y|X):")),
      tableOutput("checkboxes") 
    )
  })
  
  output[["checkboxes"]] <- 
    renderTable({tbl}, 
      rownames = TRUE, align = "c",
      sanitize.text.function = function(x) x
    )

  observeEvent(input[["show1"]], {
    if(input[["show1"]]){shinyjs::show("secondInput")} else 
      {shinyjs::hide("secondInput")}
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$showFourth,{
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
          fourthInput("input4",
                      xDflt,
                      if(isTruthy(input$input4)){input$input4[1,2]} else 
                        {input$input2[1,2]},
                      "4th input"),
          footer = modalButton("Close")
      ))
  })
  
  output$secondInput <- renderUI({
    req(input1())
    userInput("input2",xDflt,input$input1[1,2],"2nd Input")
  })
  
  outputOptions(output,"secondInput",suspendWhenHidden = FALSE) 
  
  output$plot1 <-renderPlot({
    req(input2())
    plot(rep(if(isTruthy(input$input4)){input4()[1,2]} else {input2()[1,2]}, times=10))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```